# Add keybinding to js-mode/javascript-mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, javascript, key-binding

I have added web-beautify-* to Emacs 24, so that I can run M-x web-beautify-js to pretty format my javascript source code.

I have add some keybindings for html-mode and css-mode, which work fine.

```
(eval-after-load 'sgml-mode
  '(define-key html-mode-map (kbd "C-c b") 'web-beautify-html))
(eval-after-load 'css-mode
  '(define-key css-mode-map (kbd "C-c b") 'web-beautify-css))
```

However the following snippet for js-mode and javascript-mode don't work.

```
(eval-after-load 'javascript-mode
  '(define-key js-mode-map (kbd "C-c b") 'web-beautify-js))
(eval-after-load 'js-mode
  '(define-key js-mode-map (kbd "C-c b") 'web-beautify-js))
```

How can I add custom keybindings to js-mode and javascript-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`js-mode` and its alias `javascript-mode` are defined in `js.el`, so you should use `(eval-after-load 'js ...)` instead.  The reason it works for `sgml-mode` and `css-mode` is that those modes are defined in files with the same name as the mode itself.